# Prove by using the integral test question

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Prove by using the integral test  the correctness of these results:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p} \rightarrow P>1 : \text{Convergent} , P\leq1 : \text{Diverging}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^q(n)} \rightarrow q>1 : \text{Convergent}, q\leq1 : \text{Diverging}$$
I need to do the integral for the two cases of p and q? for example if $P\leq1$ or $q\leq1$ there is option that is a fraction between $0<\dots<1$ and option that they are $P,q\leq0$ .

how I need to show it when I`m doing the integral? Or I dont need to consider the case I mentioned before ( $0<\dots<1$ and $P,q\leq0$ ).

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to consider $p\le 0$ or $q\le 0$ separately; the integral test will work just fine (you'll just get a different integration result).

Comment: take look on $$\int\frac{1}{x^p}dx = \int x^{-p} = \frac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1} + C $$ how its help me? and if $p<0$  how should the integration will be?

Comment: I need to show an example? take one time 1 and other time -1? and it will be ok to show prove it?

Comment: Your second series should start at $n=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If we assume that $p \neq 1$, then:
$$
\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^p}dx = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\dfrac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1} \right]_1^k= \lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\dfrac{x^{-(p-1)}}{1-p} \right]_1^k =  \dfrac{1}{1-p}\lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\dfrac{1}{k^{p-1}} - 1 \right]
$$
Now fill in the question marks:
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{p-1}}=\begin{cases}
?? & \text{if } p < 1 \\
?? & \text{if } p > 1 \\
\end{cases} $$

For the special case when $p=1$, we have:
$$
\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x}dx = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\ln|x| \right]_1^k = \lim_{k \to \infty} [\ln|k| - 0] = \infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second series, here is how you start

$$ \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\ln^q(x)}=\lim_{b\to \infty} \frac{1}{(1-q)\ln^{q-1}(x)}\Big|_2^{b}= \lim_{b\to \infty} \frac{1}{(1-q)\ln^{q-1}(b)} -  \frac{1}{(1-q)\ln^{q-1}(2)}.$$

Now, what do you think the condition on $q$ should be?