# Find values of $p$ for which the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty1/(n(\ln(n))^p )$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The $p$-series test for $\frac{1}{n^p}$ states that for $p>1$, the series converges to a sum.  However, the $p$ on this series is on $ln(n)$.  For this question though, I have no idea what to do with the $\ln(n)$ denominator.  Please help?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434579/prove-by-using-the-integral-test-question).

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\frac1x$, so to test the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(\ln n)^p}\;,$$

you might reasonably think of using the integral test and investigating the convergence of

$$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^p}$$

instead.

Comment: According to the integral test, if the integral function converges, then the function converges. I found the integral of that and the result I got was limit as t-> infinity of [(ln(t)^(-p+1))-(ln(2))^(-p+1))]/(-p+1)^2.  I'm trying to find what values p would make the function converge though and I'm still having issues with that.

Comment: @Myles: The lower limit is finite, so you should be looking at $$\frac1{1-p}\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac1{(\ln a)^{p-1}}$$ for $p\ne 1$. The factor of $\frac1{1-p}$ doesn’t affect convergence, so you’re really only interested in $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac1{(\ln a)^{p-1}}\;.$$ Since $\ln a\to\infty$ as $a\to\infty$, this is pretty straightforward. What happens if $p>1$? What happens if $p<1$? (You have to treat $p=1$ separately.)

Answer (score 1):

One can use the Integral Test. An alternative is to use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), which in this case asserts that our series converges precisely if the series 
$$\sum 2^n \frac{1}{2^n (\log (2^n))^p}$$
converges.So we end up looking at 
$$\sum \frac{1}{(\log 2)^p n^p}$$
which converges if and only if $p\gt 1$.